# correlogram with reliabilities in the main diagonal

Tags: r

I'm rather new to R, here is something I encountered in my first steps with it.

In some papers it is required to present a correlogram with the reliability (Cronbach Alpha) of the the correlated variables in the main diagonal (where the correlations are 1 )

an example might be 5 correlated psychometric measures

Job_ins (an average of 4 items)

Employability (an average of 4 items)

INT_to_quit (an average of 4 items)

Mobility_pref (an average of 5 items)

Career_self_mgmt (an average of 8 items)

note that in the native cor() R function the  main diagnal (the correlations of the measures with themselves) shows 1.

What I would like to do is to present internal reliablity (cronbach alphas) in the main diagonal instead.

any ideas?

Saar

Comment: What about generating the correlation matrix, `mat <- cor(...)`, (or `polychoric()`) and then update the diagonal with the values you want, `diag(mat) <- yourvalues`. Then use your preferred plotting method.

Comment: You can use `ggplot` or `qplot` to create a heatmap correlation plot.  This is also a really cool package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Comment: Hello Saar. Welcome to SO. To obtain a more concrete answer to your question, please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is my (long) solution.

```
#Loading pkgs
require(tidyverse)
require(Hmisc)
require(psych)

#Creating example data
set.seed(123) #making the random data reproducible
#Creating the items for each subject
job <- sim.congeneric(N=200, short = FALSE, low = 1, high=10,categorical=TRUE)
Employability <- sim.congeneric(N=200, short = FALSE, low = 1, high=10,categorical=TRUE)
Career <- sim.congeneric(N=200, short = FALSE, low = 1, high=10,categorical=TRUE)
#Arranging the data to one data.frame
df <- data.frame(as.data.frame(job$observed) %>% 
                   set_names(c("job1", "job2", "job3", "job4")), 
                 as.data.frame(Employability$observed) %>% 
                   set_names(c("Employability1", "Employability2",
                               "Employability3", "Employability4")), 
                 as.data.frame(job$observed) %>% 
                   set_names(c("Career1", "Career2", "Career3", "Career4")))


#Creating a vector with the Cronbach's alpha for each subject
CronAlpha <- c(
  alpha(df %>% 
          select(job1, job2, job3, job4))$total$std.alpha,
  alpha(df %>% 
          select(Employability1, Employability2,
                 Employability3, Employability4))$total$std.alpha,
  alpha(df %>% 
          select(Career1, Career2,
                 Career3, Career4))$total$std.alpha)

#Calculating the mean for each subject, than the correlations
Correlation <- df %>% 
  #Calculating the means
  mutate(job = rowMeans(data.frame(job1, job2, job3, job4), na.rm = TRUE), 
         Employability =rowMeans(data.frame(Employability1, Employability2,
                                            Employability3, Employability4), na.rm = TRUE),
         Career =rowMeans(data.frame(Career1, Career2,
                                     Career3, Career4), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  #Selecting only the vars that I want for the correlation matrix
  select(job, Employability, Career) %>%
  as.matrix() %>% 
  rcorr()

#Extracting the Pearson's r
CorrelationRs <- Correlation$r 

#Looping through the correlation data.frame and replacing with
# Cronbach's alpha
i <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(CorrelationRs)) {
  CorrelationRs[i, i] <- CronAlpha[i]

}

CorrelationRs
```

## Edit

Instead of using loop, I should use `diag()`.

```
diag(CorrelationRs) <- CronAlpha
```

Comment: Hi everyone and thank you for all the replies,sorry for my slow response. DJV i'm trying to work with what you put out here, will fill you in later

Comment: Hi DJV, it is really appreciated and looks to me like a core of a solution to my problem. So, first of all,  thank you. The problem I run into is that  R does not seem to recognize the pipe operator string ' %>% ' that you use in the definition of the vectors. It views it as an unrecognized function in all it's instances.

Comment: Hi, the %>% (pipe) is part of the magrittr/tidyvesre packages. Just install this paackges and you'll be ok :-)

Regardless to your question, I recommend you to read about it:https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-ss_ag2k9E&index=1&list=PLNtpLD4WiWbw9Cgcg6IU75u-44TrrN3A4. 
And glad to help :-) if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi again, I am trying to make this  shorter and simpler and it looks like i'm almost there. I am trying to use the diag() function. I used subset for creating the data frames, and list to create a reliability vector:        dlist=list(cronbach.alpha(JOB_ins),cronbach.alpha(Int_to_quit)
,cronbach.alpha(Employability),cronbach.alpha(Mobility_pref)
,cronbach.alpha(Career_self_mgmt))        
after that I tried to use  diag(corrmat) = for(i in dlist){i}            and I get Error in `diag<-`(`*tmp*`, value = NULL) : 
  replacement diagonal has wrong length          - any idea what am I missing?

Comment: You are right, using diag() is much better than using a loop. You should do that diag(CorrelationRs) <- CronAlpha. I will correct my script.

Comment: I  need the loop because i made a list 'dlist' of the diagonal's  cronbach alphas to create a replacement vector out of them. I then wanted to loop  the values of that vector into the correlation matrix'es main diagonal.  my correlation matrix is 'corrmat'. Printing the 'corrmat' diagonal it has 5 values, printing the loop it also has 5 values (the 5 cronbach alphas). Even so  R keeps telling me that the replacement vector has wrong length. I am missing some sort of a structural element of the diag() function. This is the code  'diag(corrmat) = for(i in dlist){i}'. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: When using diag() the variable/vector you replace with, must be with same length. For example, diag() for a correlation with 3 variables will require a vector with 3 values. If you'd use more/less it will result with an error. When you do 'diag(corrmat) = for(i in dlist){i}', logically, each time you make diag(corrmant) equal to one value. Regardless, the value must be a vector. As it says in the help for the function: in diag(x) <- value, for value either a single value or a vector of length equal to that of the current diagonal. Should be of a mode which can be coerced to that of x.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. As I said a simple print shows that both the main diagonal of 'corrmat' (The correlation matrix) and the replacement vector 'dlist' have 5 values i.e they are the same length. I made sure it is so by doing diag(corrmat) to see the  main diagonal and by printing 'dlist'. Also, for a final check I also made sure that 'dlist' is in fact a vector by using is.vector(dlist) the - result was 'TRUE' . Is a bug in the function possible here?